# What steps should I take before giving my phone to be fixed in a lab?

Tags: security, data-recovery

This is similar to [I have sold my phone on eBay. What should I do before I send it off?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4623), but in my case I'm just handing my phone off to be fixed.

I don't want to have to completely wipe or reset my phone, since it would be a pain to get everything back afterwards. Is there some middle ground, or another way to make sure some lab employee can't hack my Google account while they have my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a full backup, wipe everything, remove memory cards if present, send for repairs, restore backup after you receive.

This is neither difficult nor time-consuming if you use something like NANDROID backup.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-perform-and-restore-a-nandroid-backup/

Answer (score 1):

Change your passwords before you hand it in.  Then go into settings/applications etc and stop all the apps, clear data/cache etc.  Remove the SD card.