# Resetting Nexus 6 requires previous account

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, nexus-6, frp

- Same wifi
- previous person registered on the phone left
- I reset the phone
- after language selection (and wifi selection), I get the problem

Device says

This device was reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was **previously** synced on this device.

Does anyone know how I might fix this problem? It's an important test phone for me.

Again it’s the same wifi as previously.

I looked [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/bypass-verify-your-google-account-after-resetting/127745#127745?newreg=c7c12212f32d450fa251efb2a53453b3) but Nexus 6 does not have such a home button.

Answer (score 4):

This is an anti-theft policy put in place by Google. There is not supposed to be any way to use the phone unless you have access to a prior account used on the device. See the Nexus [documentation](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en).

The user with access to a prior account should remove that user to allow future access:

> To turn off device protection, remove your Google account from your device. If you have Developer options enabled on your device, you can also go to Settings Settings > Developer options and check "OEM Unlocking."

Answer (score 0):

Reboot to the Bootloader, see my previous post, and plug it in to a computer. On your computer, install fastboot (google "how to install fastboot on ..."). Then, open a terminal and type,

> fastboot oem unlock
>
> fastboot oem lock

If this does not work, download a nexus 6 factory image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en#shamu), and download the latest one. Double click it, and then run:

> cd ~/Downloads/name_of_file
>
> fastboot oem unlock
>
> sh flash-all.sh
>
> fastboot oem lock

Comment: Please note that this will void the waranty.

Comment: Please delete both of these incorrect answers. Only entering the prior account will work. Once this is done, use the factory reset from the Settings menu.