# "This device has been reset. Sign in to continue with the Google Account that was previously synced on this device."

Tags: factory-reset, huawei

I have a used *Huawei P smart 2019* which has just received a "factory reset". I put that in quotes because during the new configuration it asks for the last used Google account:

> Verify account
>   Sign in with your Google account.
>   This device has been reset. Sign in to continue **with the Google Account that was previously synced on this device.**

The problem is that the young user has lost his Google account access. There is *no recovery phone number, no secondary email address... no way to log into this phone.* That's why we're setting up a brand new account. The new account is ready for use but the phone is not.
--> **How do I do a *real* reset on this phone??!**

---

I have done the reset according to the official instructions:

> At the beginning you switch off the device.
>   Then hold the "Power Button" and "Volume Up" button until the Huawei logo and then the EMUI icon appears.
>   Use the volume buttons to select "wipe data / factory reset" and confirm with the power button.
>   The recovery mode then appears again. Now select "reboot system now" and the smartphone will be restarted. **The device is then reset.**

**The problem is the last part in bold:** it's not completely reset, it still wants a login using the previous account, but there is no way to provide that information.

I've found [this 5-year-old answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130860/16606) saying "*This is an anti-theft policy*" but there has to be some solution for forgetful people that have not been robbed!

---

Following the trick described in [this video starting at 4m09s](https://youtu.be/r5vVos4eMiI?t=249), I was able to bypass the dreadful screen and continue with the Android setup process, but I eventually reached a dead end where it showed me a completely blank screen and briefly showed the toast message *"Unlock device to continue"*. At this point I could only reboot or power off. That video continues with [another trick at 7m20s](https://youtu.be/r5vVos4eMiI?t=440) that does not work on this phone because the popup browser window doesn't offer the "share" function (only "copy" and "select all").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: Hi, no that doesn't answer the question because the options there do not apply to Huawei phones. They don't work.

Comment: i have recently done it one other huawei.. select some text from license info, mark it, send it, select gmail, add some email address, on final gmail setup you can reach settings menu, from there you can reach settings factory reset.. which will remove FRP (edit: seems like you found already on yt)