# Lg G4 email verification bypass cant do anything

Tags: google-account

I recently got an LG G4 phone from a friend and I was really excited until I got to the screen where it said enter the account previously any get. I was so frustrated and thought they set me up but they had also gotten it from a friend.

I did everything the YouTube told me to do except the unknown sources option is grey and it won't let me select it at all (so basically I'm stuck at step 4 of [this advice](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127745/16575) given in a related question here).

My parents don't necessarily know I have it. I don't have any money or time to send it into the Lg company and I want to get it working so I can stay in touch with my friends when I go on my trip.

What should I do ? I can't install files because it's blocked and can't add an account because every time I do it goes right back to enter the previously synced email. Would putting a SIM card in help ?? How do I completely wipe the system. My trip is in about a week help please.

Comment: Ok it's not the same because unlike everyone else I can't download the file without it saying that my phone has denied the installation of ubkoen sources to be downloaded and when I go to the settings to click on it it's grey and I can't select it or add an account it's like it's super locked. I looked up everything it recommended but it still doesn't work.

Comment: OK, so I've edited your question to make that stand out. Good luck then; unfortunately, I don't have another solution for you.

Comment: Would putting a new SIM card in it work ?

Comment: No, that wouldn't change the "FRP" (Factory Reset Protection). I've just left a note for Matthew (who gave the answers on the other question) with a pointer to yours, so he might take a look here and hopefully has a hint for you.

Comment: It would helpful if you added the exact steps you took, so we know what options are left.

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's try this,

1. Download this files:

   - [LG_FRP_TOOL_by_AndroidHero](https://mega.nz/#!6NcRgQTb!JE3B2Kt6gd1__0HYYTpj4l2O0Qbmh3sJ-ZYYIuLk5ow)
   - [LG G4 Drivers](http://tool.xcdn.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=STs33w85870646142305102/LGUnitedMobileDriver_S52MAN314AP22_ML_WHQL_Ver_3.14.1.exe)
2. Install LG G4 USB drivers
3. Disable your Anti-Virus (as it will detect the tool as a virus)
4. Put your LG G4 into Download mode by following this steps:

   - Power Off the phone
   - While Holding Vol+ connect USB cable
5. Now run the tool exe according to the OS you're using (X86 or X64)

   - [image]
6. Just follow the on-screen instructions to bypass the FRP lock
7. Done

Comment: It says I cannot open the file 

Comment: @Ayanna At what point do you see that?

Comment: When I clicked on the link then I went to downloads and I said cannot open file.

Comment: as i mentioned, you have to disable your anti-virus first!