# Phone stuck on "Sign in with a google account that was previously synced on this device"

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, motorola-moto-g3

My Motorola Moto G3 was stolen yesterday (a man on a moped grabbed it from my hand). When I got home I changed my google account password and then went to Android Device Manager and requested that the phone be locked and erased if it connects to the internet. Today someone found it on the street and contacted me (my email was displayed on the lock screen). I retrieved the phone. When I opened it the phone did a factory reset as expected.

However now when I try to login (using the account I was using before) it won't get past the "Sign in with a google account that was previously synced on this device" phase. I input my email address and my current password but it brings me back to the same screen (if i input the old password i get an "incorrect password" message). Google won't allow me to revert to the old password because it's been recently used.

Is there a way out of this?

EDIT: 
I waited the full 72 hours and then the phone let me continue with the setup process. I'm leaving the question open just in case someone has a better solution.

Comment: That is called Factory Reset Protection (FRP) started with Lollipop - [FRP](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=FRP) search on this site will help you

Comment: @beeshyams This case is different from our "daily ones": OP ***is*** the owner of the account and thus has the correct credentials – so here FRP should let him in as he can provide the details. If FRP doesn't allow access in this case either, it's a complete failure as it goes beyond its purpose. But sure, the other cases might prove helpful nonetheless.

Comment: I strongly believe that Factory reset protection (FRP) won't stop after 72 hours. Refer the following link and i think that will help you solve your problem. [How to bypass “Verify your account” (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: This solution worked for me on my HTC 10 after rooting and changing password after rooting. I was told that I had to wait fo 72 hrs. See [How to Bypass FRP Lock in LYF Phone (3 Fixes)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180123175554/http://www.newstelecom.info:80/2016/07/how-to-bypass-frp-lock-in-lyf-phone-3-fixes).

Answer (score 2):

This is the Device Protection Lock. It started from devices that was pre-installed(Shipped) with Android 5.0(Lollipop) and up.

It's basically asking you to sign in to any Google account that's synced or added to the device.

To verify if your account is synced to your device, please go to Google Dashboard (google.com/dashboard), and sign in with your Google account. Go to Android, then compare if one of the devices listed is the device that is currently locked out. If it is, then you can unlock the device with your Google account. If not, then you need to use another Google account that may be synced to your device.

If you can't remember your credentials, you can reset your password by going to Google.com/accounts/recovery, but if your change your password before or after Factory Device Reset, you need to wait for 24 hours to sign back on the device and complete the first time setup.

If you still can't get in with the correct Gmail account, waiting 24 hours if you reset your password, then you need to contact the Device Manufacturer for Warranty/Repair options.