# ZTE PRESTIGE n9132 FRP?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

Has anybody found any loop holes to FRP BYpass for this ZTE model Android?  Plz do share!

Comment: Refer this Question: [How to bypass “Verify your account” (Factory Reset Protection)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection/127745#127745)