# After Factory Reset - Please Sign in using one of the owner's account for this device - Asus Zenfone 2

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, asus-zenfone-2

I'm using Asus Zenfone 2 laser Android device. For a specific reason I did factory reset. After reset I tried to access my mobile. It asked me to use Google account which I used before in that device for sync. I did that too. But again and again i'm seeing "***Please sign in using one of the owner's account for this device***". I tried so many times using all my previous Gmail ids which ever used in my mobile. How to resolve this issue? I checked in Google and got results for some Bypass Technic which I don't want. I need the root cause and the proper solution.

***Note:*** Before resetting my mobile I changed the password of my Gmail id and I used the updated password. I'm not sure whether it would be the reason. If so how to fix this?

Comment: This is a specific feature - FRP (Factory Reset Protection), and there are many questions here to suggest resolutions. Here is a starting [query](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Factory+Reset+Protection%22+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) with similar questions and answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: @wbogacz Please not I didn't need to By Pass "Verify your account" and I needed the root cause. I got the solution too. `I checked in Google and got results for some Bypass Technic which I don't want. I need the root cause and the proper solution.` - notes from my question.

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved in the next 48 hours of resetting my mobile. The reason for this issue was changing my Gmail password before resetting my mobile. If we changed the password we needs to want for 48 hours after resetting our mobile to Sign in using our already used account in our device.

Because device will expect our old password for 48 hours then the updated password will be acceptable for the device us to enter the Main screen of our device.

If any one changed the password and experiencing this issue, please wait for another 48 hours. Your issue will be resolved in 2 days ;-)