# how to by pass google account on my itel 1556

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode

My phone is bringing me tó write the google account which was previously synced into the phone but this was not mine í just bought it from someone.how can í do?[image]

Comment: Í can't go any further from the re

Comment: @jackson mnanka FRP on Android 5.0 can be easily bypassed. Was the phone locked with a pin, or a model or a password before you reset it?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest performing a factory reset.  You should be able to do this by opening settings and navigating to Backup & reset.  Here you should find Factory data reset.

You may want to remove any SD card(s) and reformat ( overwrite ).

Comment: Í can't go any further from there

Comment: We should attempt a factory reset from the boot loader then.  Power down the phone, then when starting it hold volume down.  

This should reveal a menu with a Factory option.

Comment: @George Oscar Bluth's This is exactly what has resulted from a factory reset. The phone had the FRP enabled. So you can attempt as many reset as you can, the phone will stick there.

Comment: Have you reviewed this post? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection