# How can I remove Android devices from my Google account?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-account, huawei

Why cannot I remove Android phones from my Google account? I don't find any button for remove! I want to do that since I did factory reset of my phone and when I login again, it says (login using the owner's account of this phone) so I though if I remove it from my Google account, it will help. Kindly, can you guide me toward removing it?

[image]

Comment: That's odd.  Are the other entries for that device missing the "Remove" button as well?  I see this for mine: http://i.imgur.com/enwlF1N.png (Note to others, that page can be accessed from https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity)

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes all of them have no remove button!! I am trying to workaround this message that I am getting when I login my phone via Google account `please sign in using one of the owner's account for this device` even though I am using the correct account and correct password !!!

Comment: @MatthewRead I think it is due this http://www.pcnexus.net/2015/12/what-is-factory-reset-protection-google-72-hour-lockout-android-lollipop.html

Comment: Oh, I see!  Yes, to get through Factory Reset protection you will typically need to log into the device with the _first_ account that was added on the device prior to the factory reset.  If that's not possible, there are more solutions here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/1465