# How can i Bypass the owners Google account verification on Android v10

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

My friend bought a used LG Android v10 T-Mobile phone and she factory reset it immediately because she didn't know the screen lock password. Unaware of the new security lock option for Google account. It says connect to Wi-Fi. Then press next. It says 'checking connection' and  'verifying Google account'. Then it directs me to the sign in requirement page for the phone set up and asks for my e-mail address.

When I put my e-mail and password in, Google security account verification calls phone to give code. I then have to type in the 6 digit code provided. It checks information and accepts my account info but before next step it redirects me to "please sign in using the owners account that was previously synced to device" and I don't have any way of knowing a name or e-mail of original owner.

Is there a way for me to bypass this Google security verification so I can use this phone?

Comment: i hope this helps. [check 2nd answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the previous owner of the phone and see if you can have them set a temporary password to get through it.