# wipping data after factory reset

Tags: samsung, data

to clear my data in my android 10 phone after factory reset,i was told that i must put trivial files until the memory full,since my memory is large 256gb,i filmed a short video and then copied and pasted the same video several times with change them names until the memory is full ,im asking the copied files can overwriting data after factory reset,or  must new files

(i also use disk digger wipe free space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Device with Google Android 10 (assuming that the device came with Android 10 and wa snot upgraded to it) are encrypted by default. If you perform a factory reset the encryption key has been deleted and thus the file content can't be recovered.

Comment: Factory reset wipes data and clears encryption keys. Even if deleted data is recovered, it is not decryptable.

Comment: \* except for unencrypted custom ROMs

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, my problem i did , Factory Reset, but I did not delete my Google account after or before the factory reset and i sold the phone, does this decrypt the deleted data or not,  because i  heard this if i do not delete my google account before i do factory reset  is ithe device enter Google Reactivation Lock ! Please help me understand this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost pin, no Google account, can I factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172308/lost-pin-no-google-account-can-i-factory-reset)