# android 10 encryption google frp

Tags: google, frp

hello i have android 10 phone i did , Factory Reset, but I did not delete my Google account after or before the factory reset and i sold the phone, does this decrypt the deleted data or not, because i heard this if i do not delete my google account before i do factory reset is the device enter Google Reactivation Lock ! Please help me understand this whats that mean ?**strong text**

Comment: How did you perform the factory reset. From within Android or via recovery (boot by pressing certain hardware key while boot)? If you perform factory reset from within Android the Google account is automatically deleted as you have verified you are the device owner as the device is unlocked. Only if you perform factory from recovery (like a device thief would do) FRP is activated.

Comment: *"does this decrypt the deleted data or not"* - No, deleted data cannot decrypted. not related to FRP at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wipping data after factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242175/wipping-data-after-factory-reset)