# I just got a samsung galaxy tab 3 and i have not used it in a long time and now i cant remember my password

Tags: lock-screens

I need help  with my samsung galaxy i got it but forgot th right passwrd is there  any way you guys can some how help me get  it back?

Comment: Nobody can help get **your** password back

Comment: OMG! People are now asking help to remember their passwords?

Answer (score 0):

**this method will delete all user data**

Turn off the device. Then, hold the volume up, home button and power button simultaneously until you see the recovery screen. Now, use the volume keys to select Wipe data/factory reset. Scroll down to yes, delete all user data and click confirm. After that, go to "reboot system now"

Comment: You need to [bypass Factory Reset Protection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739)

Comment: Only if he doesn't know the password of his Google account. If he just forgot the pin / pattern the method I described will work just fine

Comment: @iBug OP didn't say they forgot their Google account credentials ;)