# How to bypass FRP on Google Pixel(1st Gen)?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, google-pixel

First, It's not a duplicate post. I have already tried the methods written for different phones like [this generic one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection) but it's for LG and Samsung phones.

Also, I have watched [this video](https://youtu.be/GFn5spEMHp0?t=1m36s) but "*Maps*" is not shown as an option along with *cut* and *copy*.

Please help me get this phone to work.

Comment: Try this: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/google/google-pixel/faq/bypass-google-verification/ [Edited by Moderator Firelord]

Comment: This has been discussed on [site meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2168/131553) and currently all questions dealing with FRP are marked as dupe, though that question is for a specific device but the logic in the answer linked earlier holds