# Bypass Account Security

Tags: accounts

I received four used a6 tablets in a school closing sale.
I want to login but need to verify the account.

I tried rebooting, but still get blocked.

NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection/127745#127745). Google has updated so that fix no longer works.

Comment: There are hundreds of videos on the internet that explain how to bypass the FRP. You need to try them all and perhaps you will succeed. As you pointed, Google regularly patches every flaws that can help bypass the security lock.

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with the A6, whatever that may be, but can you not boot into recovery and factory reset it?  Are you trying to get into the gmail account or the device?

EXPERIMENTAL:
I don't know much about Samsung devices, or the A6, but could you load into fastboot, or it's Samsung equivalent, and flash TWRP / CWM, then root the device, do a full system-wide reformat, and install a custom ROM?  Please check before doing this, as I have no idea what I'm talking about in regards to this device.

Cheers,

Neveraht.

P.S. : I want one of those, and they're not supercheap; how much did you get *four* of them for?

Comment: Try doing some researches instead of giving bad information this may mislead people!

Comment: I explicitly said that I was only giving ideas, and that I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: So use the comment section to suggest ideas instead of giving an actual answer.