# How to lock phone with no google password

Tags: google-account

Phone got stolen and they changed my Google password how/can lock phone through Google account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat This question isn't about FRP at all: it's about locking a stolen phone through Android Device Manager when the owner has lost access to the Google account.

Comment: Okay thanks guess I misread the question as one of those locked-out questions..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the forgotten password option with any Google service to gain access to your Google account again, after you have successfully recovered your account then you can move onto the locking.

First, log into your Find My Device using the recovered account credentials and then either choose to lock and wipe the device or locate the device.

Lock and wipe will lock your device and do a factory reset, while locate will give you the GPS location if it is enabled on the device and the device has an active network connection.

Please note that if the person has changed your password, they've probably changed many things, it could be that they've removed your device from your Google devices, or even fully disabled the security features that help find your device.

A google password is not just for your device, it is linked to all google related services like YouTube, Gmail etc....

[Find My Device - Google Android](https://www.google.com/android/find)