# How can I bypass Android FRP?

Tags: factory-reset

My child has transferred phones. I now have his old phone and want to repurpose it, sell it, donate it, give it to a co-worker, use it myself, etc.

The FRP protection prevents me from doing that. I understand the point of FRP but the logic behind it is somewhat flawed and doesn't cover a multitude of legitimate scenarios. ***I own this phone, not my child!***

My child is not present to provide credentials to bypass this feature. How do I reset this essentially bricked device without having to use hacking software?

[image]

Note: this question does look a bit like a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection), but none of the answers there are acceptable or work.

Comment: If none of the solutions work, it's advised that you supply more info, e.g. the device's model, Android version, *how* the given solution fails.

Comment: Have you actually factory-reset the device yet?