# Remotely disable Factory Reset Protection (FRP) for a damaged phone

Tags: factory-reset, touchscreen, frp

I have a brand new Samsung J6, worked without problems for a few days and suddenly got stuck on the Samsung logo when powering on. Managed to enter the recovery menu and delete the cache partition, after which the phone started, but the touchscreen wasn't working. I tried restarting in Safe Mode, but the problem persisted. After that, I went back to the recovery menu and did a factory reset. Touchscreen still not responding to any input.

I contacted my carrier to send the phone for service, but they require the phone to be unlinked from a Google account (basically, Factory Reset Protection). As far as I know, FRP won't trigger if you perform the factory reset from the settings app on the phone, but that's not an option due to the non functional touchscreen.

I've been looking at what the Google console offers, but there doesn't seem to be a way to decouple the phone from the account, it's mostly to deal with lost or stolen devices. I tried the remote wipe feature on another phone, but that still triggers FRP.

Linked account is part of G Suite, though I don't think there's any special phone management system in use.

Is there a page where I can tell Google to stop associating that particular phone to my account?

I've found nothing of the sort in the following pages:

https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity
https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone
https://www.google.com/android/find

Comment: old question, but simplest workaround is using external keyboard and mouse connected via usb-otg adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can log in to Gmail from other system. Go to Manage my account. Under security option you will find devices Activity. You can select your mobile and choose forget devices. This will remove your mobile from Gmail.

If you can use other working screen. Start mobile and use find my device to remove account.

Comment: I don't think this suggestion would help, but it can be a step to achieve something else. See this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199824

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to remove your Google account from the phone before performing the reset. Now that you have reset the phone, your carrier service technician won't be able to get back into the phone without your Google login credentials. The only way I was able to overcome this was to reflash the stock ROM. Then when the phone boots up, it will be seen as a new device. That worked on my phone. Samsung may have defeated this method on the J6.

Comment: Reflashing stock ROM would not always disable FRP. In my case, overwriting FRP partition or  using a custom ROM worked.

Comment: Sadly, due to the non functional touchscreen, it wasn't possible to interact with the phone to remove the account.

Comment: I had assumed FRP works by checking the phone's IMEI against a Google database, but Firelord's comment implies it's done locally. In that case, not much chance to be able to unlink the phone from the account from the web, but it would allow someone to overwrite the FRP info if they have physical access to the phone (which, IMHO, defeats the purpose of theft protection).