# Google account was hacked: how do I get my phone working with my new account?

Tags: factory-reset, google, zte

My Google account was hacked, I think because somebody SIM-hacked my T-Mobile account. (Thus the Google account recovery process was short-circuited.) I've asked Google for help via the recovery process but I'm not at all hopeful. In the meantime (as the recovery process suggests!!!) I've got a new Google account.

Now I'd like to get my Android phone (ZTE Axon 7) working with the new account, but even after a factory reset it *still* wants to access the Google account it thinks is associated with the phone. In other words, from the "Let's get started" screen, it won't take my new account login, instead insisting that I provide the password to the former account.

Can anything be done to deal with this problem?

Comment: they claim it is working (i don't believe it) but give it a try http://www.teamgsmedge.com/2018/02/bypass-google-account-zte-axon-7-mini.html

Comment: @alecxs yes I saw that, I think ZTE patched the vulnerability that allowed the USB connection to work. Also that was for an Axon 7 Mini, not an Axon 7 (though I think the software is pretty similar).

Comment: Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: Please look for posts before asking another question

Answer (score 3):

The hindsight version:

Factory reset protection is supposed to prevent thieves from stealing your phone and using it. To do this, the phone requires you to login with a Google account that was on the phone before the factory reset. Add the new account to the phone before the factory reset. Or, alternately, remove all accounts before the factory reset.

Comment: You cannot remove accounts without the account password.

Answer (score 1):

When that happened to me, I had to flash the rom again. Some phones are protected against this, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: That would probably work, but it's pretty drastic and I'm not sure how to do that on this particular phone.

Comment: Instructions for your device are here:

https://ztefirmware.com/zte-axon-7-a2017

Answer (score 1):

Goto Settings option. In settings find Account option. Scroll through account option to find out the hacked account and remove it from the device. Then in the same menu, add a new Google account