# How to remove someone else's Google account from the Pixel 3a?

Tags: google-account, 9.0-pie, password, google-pixel, frp

So my friend has his partner's Google Pixel 3a with him. She did *factory reset* and gave it to him before leaving for a semester abroad. She forgot to remove her Google account before performing the reset though.

The phone runs on Android 9. Now when my friend tries to set up the device, he is asked to log in to an account which was associated with this particular device beforehand. Since he doesn't know the password of his partner's account, he is unable to use the device as his own.

Is there a way to fix this without having to ask the password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Answer (score 0):

He can't remove it without the password. But his partner can, by accessing the Google account and deleting the phone from the list of devices active on that account. This link will take the original account holder to the appropriate page:

https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web