# How can I factory/hard reset/wipe a Nokia 2.2 (TA-1188) without a (windows) PC?

Tags: factory-reset, linux, hard-reset, nokia, nokia-2

Having looked around hither and thither now for a night as to how to factory reset a Nokia 2.2, I am still a bit confused and unable to do it.

Holding **volume-down + power on** brings me to a boot screen saying *"=> FASTBOOT mode"*, but no buttons are having effect after that. Apparently the next step is to connect it via usb cable to a Windows computer with some specific tool or another installed on it?

I've seen people in youtube videos apparently using a Windows tool called **'[InfinityBox AST](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinitybox)'** , and I have tried running that in a Windows VM, but for some (in my opinion) suspect reason, 'InfinityBox' decides to detect that's it's being ran under VirtualBox, and instantly refusing to launch with a message specifically stating that it wont run on a Virtual Machine.

*(This 'vm detector' behavior is enough of a reason to me being quite reluctant and suspicious to even having attempted to run the utility trough Wine/Proton)*

- **Is there really no way to factory reset a Nokia 2.2 TA-1188 cellphone *without* requiring an actual physical (Windows) PC in addition to some shady unofficial utility made by neither Google nor Nokia?**
- If not possible without a PC, is there some Linux software solution able to perform the task?

Comment: InfinityBox is professional hardware (for which you have to buy software licence codes every year) https://multi-com.pl/multicom/pimg/infinity_box_blue_500.jpg the standard way for controlling android devices from pc is platform-tools https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads and each OEM have there own flash tools of course. for mediatek chipset you can try https://spflashtool.com

Comment: if you plan to sell your phone, make sure you enabled oem unlocking in developer settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4jrdu1PhRI OR removed your google account before factory reset https://youtu.be/_jw1h1Ymoas

Comment: [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739)

Comment: from any PC login to google with the phones bonded google play account, use Find My Device and set a temporary screen lock (4-5 digits) under Secure Device, or use the Erase Device option https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager if you cannot login to google use the forgot password option and leave phone online for ~ 72 hours after changing the google play account password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now been in contact with Nokia support; Apparently **there is no way**, at least with that specific phone in question *(or the specific firmware ver.?)*, to get it unlocked/factory reset, for the common user.

Fortunately, the dude at Nokia support chat checked the [IMEI](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imei)'s of it, and it turned out it was still within warranty, by a hair's length. So having contacted the chain that sold it, a second time, it seems the local store will be replacing the phone tomorrow.

As such, and though depending on varying consumer rights in countries; My hindsight tip would be to **first *press the seller* with the fact**, rather than immediately *"making an appointment"* trough [Nokia's online warranty form](https://nokia.ebuilder.com/nb_NO/model), to send the phone away to Nokia as was suggested by Nokia support; Simply for Nokia to do the *"magic"* of unlocking ***your* bought and paid for property(!!)**, and sending it back to you ..Something which no doubt would have added considerably more time than the store simply replacing the device and having to deal with manufacturer warranty themselves.

**BTW:** If you are indeed able to get to the *'downed droid'* splash logo on your Nokia 2.2 (TA-1188) trough any physical button-combo, you just might want to confirm with [Nokia support](https://www.nokia.com/phones/support/) whether your phone might be a counterfeit one or not, or to verity that it's not been flashed with unoriginal and thus possibly tampered-with firmware.. *(just push your way trough their silly chat-bot for a few questions, and then an actual human will respond to your inquiry on the other end)*

**PS:** Google *did* eventually come trough with assistance in recovering my brother's hacked/locked Google account. (takes ~3.5 days).. But seemingly, that process also unlinks it from the/any associated device(s). Which is good, from a security perspective.. ..Though the problem becomes then, that that effectively makes it impossible to reset from online Android Device Manager as shown trough some online *how-to*'s .. *Meaning, the phone would've basically be considered as good as destroyed, if it had not been for it still being within warranty timerange... (personally, I'll be looking at Librem phone for myself in the near future, rather than risk experience a similar ordeal and frustration)*

Comment: I'll leave this unaccepted for a while, in case someone might have some further input as either comment or answer.

Comment: first thing i always do on each friends and family members buyed android phone is enable OEM unlocking, usb-debugging and initial connect to their PCs (authorize RSA-Key, installing drivers, backup software, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> (not Volume Down). Keep holding until you see the android logo. It will take you to the Recovery mode. Use the volume keys to select "Wipe data/factory reset". Then press on the <kbd>Power</kbd> button. Choose Yes to wipe all user data.

When completed, you can select "Reboot system now".

Comment: I'm fairly sure i tried that numerous times, with the only result being it rapidly rebooting over and over to a green "android one" splash boot screen, and if let go of the buttons, landing at regular start screen.  Volume Down + Power appears to be the only button combo that has any effect in that regard, even when holding the buttons in for up to 30-40 seconds..

Comment: by green "android one" , i mean the green logo on white background. (comment editing timed out)

Comment: Please see my 'BTW:' here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220754/291009 .. May i ask if you perhaps bought yours second hand?

Answer (score 0):

**factory reset from fastboot**

enable OEM unlocking in developer options first

```
sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
fastboot flashing unlock
```

and if you want to re-lock bootloader

```
fastboot flashing lock
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: you should clarify current state of device. please note factory reset will only delete userdata. it does neither repair modified partitions nor remove FRP

Comment: The problem, and the reason the phone needs factory resetting is that it's locked with numeric code, so it's not possible to get to the android settings menus.

Comment: _fastboot flashing unlock_ leaves the computer standing at "< waiting for any device >"

Comment: OEM unlocking is required for fastboot. contact the owner

Comment: The owner is my brother, who i'm supposed to unlock it for.