# Alcatel A574BL unrootable, FRP unbypassable

Tags: rooting, frp

FRP bypass unsuccessful have tried every method posted on YouTube. Managed  to get browser, download apps, etc. Certain limits that i really want to be rid of. Phone wont root trying superuser, kingroot..any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)