# Google email forgotten after hard reset

Tags: samsung, google-account, hard-reset, frp

My father did a hard reset on his Samsung A10 to give to me as a gift, but he forgot his password and Google email.

I checked the RootJunky video mentioned in [this topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection) but it seems that is not working anymore.

Is there another way to bypass the "Verify the account"? The A10 is unrooted and I don't want to do it.

Comment: check SIM method i posted in comments

Comment: You can recover the Google user name by using the phone number or a recovery e-mail address set in the account: https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/usernamerecovery?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin

Comment: @Robert It was not any SIM card in that A10 because my father fixed his old phone before change the SIM card to the new phone. So it is not possible to recover his account by the phone number.

Comment: @alecxs I will check that video, thank you for replying. However, as I said to Robert, this A10 never has a SIM card inside. Is still possible to use that method with another SIM card?

Comment: @alecxs IT WORKS!!!! If you post the link on the answer here I will accept it.