# Flashing Custom Rom

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, google, frp

How do I choose the correct firmware for my phone?
I have a Samsung a310f that is frp locked on the back IT'S written yately "gugg", UK which could mean that it was made in the UK or for the UK now when I am on SamMobile I don't know if choosing the one for my country or the one that made the phone.

Comment: first remove FRP then goto settings and enable OEM unlocking in developer options, otherwise you can't flash custom ROM https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection#comment285010_127739

Comment: I can't get all the methods from YouTube to work in removing frp, what can I do

Comment: ask the previous owner for google password

Comment: The phone was stolen

Comment: [Bluetooth method](https://www.techeligible.com/2018/08/04/bypass-google-frp-samsung-galaxy-a3)

Comment: [PC method](https://www.techeligible.com/2019/02/19/frp-bypass-galaxy-a7-a5-a3)

Answer (score 0):

For this model you can flash many official ROM versions.

https://fw.updato.com was a good source of download collection and tutorials in early years, but this site became worst since they monetarized everything

You can flash with [Odin](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) or [Heimdall](https://www.glassechidna.com.au/heimdall)

Be aware there is downgrade protection for bootloader and flashing another ROM does not remove FRP lock. Only the methods for [by-pass FRP](https://www.techeligible.com) may vary.

For Android 7 Nougat [CF-Auto-Root](https://download.chainfire.eu/933/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-a3xelte-a3xeltexx-sma310f.zip) is available but it requires OEM unlocking in developer options

Flashing [TWRP](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxya32016exynos.html) is another option but it requires OEM unlocking, too

Comment: I have heard about "combination ROM" will help to by-pass FRP. Also some people report successful downgrade, i will revise my answer when i am back at PC https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3586815