# Relocked bootloader

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock

I had unlocked bootloader on Moto g5s, and then relocked it again with  fastboot oem lock, now it shows warning "Your device has loaded a different operating system" and when turned on, asks a password
is it a brick now?
How can this be solved

Comment: @alecxs, I actually failed the password as many times, that it made hard reset... I couldn't do even hard reset via recovery mode. So, as far as unlocking it again, I have tried but it says 'invalid boot state', and does not unlock.

Comment: what kind of password protection, are you talking about [FRP](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739)? how do you know bootloader is locked, and how is the bootloader warning message related to password protection?