# Bypassing account verification on a Nook BNTV450

Tags: nook

I recently bought a Nook BNTV450 from someone on Ebay, to replace a like model that I used for years until it was damaged in a fall.  I got stymied early in the setup by the message "This device was reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was previously synced on this device."

I reported this to the seller, who simply apologized and offered a refund.  Probably I should just give up and buy a newer model Nook, but I really liked my old device, and this is also my third attempt at replacing it (don't ask) and I hate to admit total defeat.

First, I contacted two separate chat support people via the Barnes and Noble web site, who both told me to do a factory reset from the recovery menu.  That didn't work, of course.  Then I called and spoke to a real person, who just flatly told me it was impossible to use the device without the previous owner logging in.

Nearly all pages I've found when searching for the lock message have focused on phones, not Nooks, but [one answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection?newreg=6d061791e94547359925ad9ee7452d3c) on this site got me reasonably far; I'm able to access the general Settings menu.  However, when I repeatedly click the "Android version" button on the "About tablet" menu, it doesn't activate the developer settings.  Instead, one of the following two images fills the screen:

[image: Nook image 1]

[image: Nook image 2]

All I can do at this point is click the back arrow to return to the "About tablet" menu.  Develop settings are not enabled.

Other pages suggest one should click repeatedly on other "About tablet" buttons to activate developer settings, such as the "Build number," but only the "Android version" button has any effect on my device.

Even if I were able to turn on developer settings, the Stack Exchange answer I linked to above says the next step is to attach the device to one's computer with a USB cable, but the Nook doesn't have a USB port.  Then one is supposed to run an adb command.  I've installed Android Studio for Linux, but it doesn't come with an adb command.

Is there any way to reset my Nook so I can use it, either by continuing the process described above, or any other way?

Comment: You realize the Nook was almost certainly stolen, right?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No, I don't realize that.  Is that a much more likely scenario than the owner not realizing they needed to log out of their Google account before doing a factory reset?  If I had sold my old Nook, I wouldn't have thought to do that.

Comment: If that were the case, then couldn't you just send it back and have the seller unlock it and then send it back to you?

Comment: It's worth a try, I suppose.

Comment: The alternative would be the previous owner provided you with their Google credentials so you can setup the device. Not likely they'd do that, but they could change them before and after to be "safe" again themselves.