# where i can find combination firmware for samsung A207F(A20s)

Tags: samsung

I need `combination firmware/file` for remove **FRP** from my Samsung A207F(A20s).

Where from i can find it?

I very searched for it but could not found any things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: @alecxs i've seen `combinationfirmware.com/combination-samsung-galaxy-a20s` before, there is no any link for download. you see any download link for `combination` file?

Comment: @alecxs yeh, i've tried the sim method, but does not work on android 10 an latest security patch update

Comment: bootloader has downgrade protection i doubt you will find combination rom which is flashable on latest version. just wait a year or so..