# Turn off frp after reset

Tags: frp

I have an Aspera Jazz 7.0 which had frp  turned on. Because of weird network issue, I had to reset it. But I forgot my account password and the phone number. I can go with a new account, but I can't turn off the frp . I tried fastboot. But can't hard reset it. How can I turn it off?

Comment: You can't... That is the point of Factory Reset Protection and there is a "duplicate" question about this very topic posted regularly. Marking as duplicate and noting answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)