# How to fix error messages (failed /efs unmount; failed to find misc partition) on stock recovery screen?

Tags: samsung

This Samsung phone was given to me. I had no clue about the frp when I reset it.  I wondered the easiest way to get past it because I'm like two days into starting to learn this stuff and I'd like my phone back. There are two messages on the recovery screen I don't understand. The first is:

> `E:ensure_path_unmounted failed to unmount /efs (device or resource busy)`

I would also like to add that I did factory reset it once without the sim card in it I'm not sure if that affects anything.

The second message this one is at the bottom (the other is at the top under the menu says):

> `E:failed to open /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc: No such file or directory`

Actually reading through it there are two more similar to these two.

Comment: When you got the phone was it working?

Comment: Yes and the verizon software update and repair thing was working on it all night but I don't know how to put it into the proper mode to transfer the software to it without getting into the phone which I still couldn't do.  Oddly, I restarted it a moment ago and got a weird green screen with gears saying android was starting which I'd never seen before.  I tried all those tutorials where they get to google, I couldn't before but my screen isn't quite so monotone now so maybe I can now who knows.  I'll try and let you know.

Comment: ignore that messages, that are leftovers from previous rom version. missing misc partition is due a change to fota partition, most likely some lazy samsung developer forgot to fix recovery.fstab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: frp = "factory reset protection", nice to know. Before you buy a device, first always google, does it have similar dishonest practice. If yes, **boycott the whole manufacturer**.