# Remove FRP after Hard Reset Hyundai Tablet

Tags: frp

This is my first post. I've a big problem. In my job, we've tablets **Hyundai Koral 10x2**, for any reason someone did a **hard reset** from `factory mode` and now we can't pass the screen **google account** 'cause the person what did the **hard reset forgot the mail & pass**. So, anyone know how can i remove `FRP`? I have not found anything on **youtube** or **google**

**Tablet Data** from **Android Recovery**:

```
Hyundai/Koral_10x2/HT10004X16
8.1.0/OPM6.171019.030.E1/101345
```

i can't use `adb commands`, from **sdcard** i can't install apps 'cause always shows error: **Signature verification failed. Error 21.**

any solution? please

**UPDATE**

Things what i do to solve the problem:

> > > 1st method: changing language to pyckknñ, insert new wifi network, long press in space key, press in green letter, click in green button, click in option with rigth row, click in three points (up|rith) press in second option, open in Switch, now in the video show a shared button this not see in my tablet (shared option is'nt visible like the video) if i touch the video, this show a shared button after i press shared this open YouTube Go at this point all looks good but YouTube Go show: please login in your google account and when i try to do it, same error: this device was sinchronized with another account. [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYdExc-DcGM)

> > > 2nd method: same like 1st but in this case, i search delete or disable apps android in section [tutorial link](https://youtu.be/XssoWIL65e8?t=152) i open the result, i click in the first link, this shows me a settings apps, i down and open youtube settings, click in first option, this open new screen, click in last option this try to open youtube but this close and show error that youtube go has stopped.

> > > 3rd method: in google account long press in @ key but this not shows me a settings option.

> > > 4th method: like first method but using TalkBack [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XYUfHmqfWU)

> > > 5th method: triyng in google account long press in word and press search in google but this no appear in the device [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYdBwj3haCM)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

Comment: Unfortunately not work to me @beeshyams

Comment: i've update the question with the thing what i try to solve my problem @alecxs

Answer (score 1):

[rkflashtool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rkflashtool) can dump firmware off device and write single partition/offset. It is therefore capable for erase FRP partition. this [documentation](https://github.com/neo-technologies/rkflashtool) might help to figure out usage.

There are maybe easier methods for example [talkback](https://www.techeligible.com) method which is pretty generic (check [youtube](https://www.google.com/search?q=rockchip+rk3126+frp))

Comment: can you edit your post with an example or a tutorial with vieo? sorry, i don't understand correclty the documentation

Comment: only someone with RockChip device could do that

Comment: oh, ah, okey. I need use linux to do that, right? (Sorry, i don't very good with this things, basically i'm new)

Comment: create pendrive with rufus or unetbootin