# Password unlock from recovery menu

Tags: recovery-mode

What do I door the steps to reset or unlock the phone pin on a Motorola phone.. I have already powered device off and am. Ow at.the recovery menu so what do I do to unlock this phone e even have the mount option but Nothing happens when I choose it and bottom of phone screen says
Supported API:3 and has mounted/system 3 times under the api  anyone help me

Comment: there is no such password unlock from recovery menu. you can factory reset from recovery menu (but won't remove [FRP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection))