# Cannot verify Google account after factory resetting Huawei tablet

Tags: google-account, huawei, locked-out, frp

There is a tablet Huawei AGS-W09, which I have not used for a while.
I have restored it to factory default. When it starts, it asks for the Google credentials that were used in it; this is probably an anti-theft mechanism.

I provide the Google username and password, but then it requires phone verification. I know the phone number, but it does not exist anymore, since I did not add credit to it for years.
Even with a PC, the same thing, I cannot log in to this Google account, because it asks for phone verification.
If I ask Google to recover my account, it just asks for "the last password I remember", I enter the current password, and then says they cannot help.

Is there any way to recover the Google account and/or the tablet?

Comment: Unless you can recover that account then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have a "canonical" Q&A for bypassing the FRP: [How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/44325). As for the Google account itself, I'm afraid it's out of scope for this site, you might need to [per use their help support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439).