# Factory reset protection on Galaxy S9+

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, frp

I have a new Galaxy S9+ that was setup before a vacation. When I returned, my code did not work. I did not link the google account to a phone, nor do I remember the one used during setup.

I've done a factory reset and now I'm being required to enter password or use a Google account. I can do neither. I've attempted to use the apk after the reset, but the tablet does not see the usb device. File manager does not open when I plug it in. Is there any way to factory reset this? Samsung support is horrible so far.

Comment: Duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253511/2241

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have a "canonical" Q&A for bypassing the FRP: [How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/44325). As for the Google account itself, I'm afraid it's out of scope for this site, you might need to [per use their help support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439).