# frp and screen lock issues vivo y02

Tags: lock-screens, google-account, hard-reset, frp, vivo

I received my vivo y02 v2236 as a gift, unfortunately, someone mixed it up with their phone i cannot locate the owner and I am stuck with this. I cannot bypass FRP and screen lock as I don't have the credentials as I received it as a gift. I tried the factory reset still no luck, Android version 12 32GB storage

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please follow [the canonical FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/44325) about bypassing FRP.