# Reset MotoG Play, unusable without PIN

Tags: factory-reset, motorola-moto-g, frp, motorola-moto-g-play

I recently inherited a Moto G Play (2021) from a family member who quit using it a while back. I factory reset it using the BIOS (hold volume up + power), but when going through the setup again, it's asking for the previous PIN on the phone. My relative doesn't remember it anymore, and they've since deleted the Google account that used to be associated as well.

Is there a way I can use the phone again? I'm okay with custom ROMs and such, and I actually don't even need to activate the cell service, WiFi only would be fine.

Comment: Standard advice on FRP: [How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/44325)